# Interactive 2D map in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shapes, interactive

I am pretty new to Unity but I have been able to find my way around. However, I have encountered a problem and no matter how much I google it I can't seem to find a solution that works. I am probably just doing something silly. Any help would be appreciated. I posted to the Unity forum but no one is responding so I figured I would give Stack Overflow a chance too.

So what I am trying to do is to create a 2D map in Unity. This map will be used to navigate through a 3D world. The map must be clickable because I will start with a world map and then based off the user's click, the map needs to change to that country's map. I have talked to different people and the way I want to go is with shapefiles since they already contain the information as to where the country and state boundaries are. In addition, I know I will have to work with shapefiles in the future so I figured I would just get some practice with them now. I wanted to start small so I downloaded a zipfile that contained the shapefile for the united states. I downloaded QGIS per a forums instructions and opened the shapefile in that software. In QGIS I was able to highlight individual states as shown in the photo below

[image: What I get from QGIS. Still want the highlighting and selecting in Unity]

Now I want this same functionality in Unity, except I don't just want to highlight it, I also want it to be clickable and to be able to identify that state as Montana.

So from here I was able to converted this file to a DXF and then converted that to an FBX. But after that I am lost. I am not sure I even had to do those conversions.

If anyone could help me in this endeavor I would great appreciate it! Again I am new to Unity so if you could keep that in mind I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The thing is you need to have access to separated shapes of states - can you check if your FBX file has divided it self into parts that are states? If yes then it is very easy to do what you want.

Comment: Do you know how I could possibly check that? I can't open my FBX in QGIS. I converted it from a shapefile to DXF by the QGIS application and then to FBX using the AutoCad free converter. But I am not sure what application I can use to open and view the FBX. I can't open it in QGIS or Maya. Any suggestions?

Comment: Import this FBX into Unity3D and check if it was divided by placing its prefab in the scene, and opening the tree.

Comment: If you don't know how to do it - upload the FBX somewhere and share the link with us - then I will check it.

Comment: Thank you! I uploaded it to drive. Let me know if you can download it. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2I8fexDHn-WSnZ0MThxczByRkU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Unfortunately the FBX is empty - I mean without any mesh.

Comment: Hm ok then I must be converting it wrong? Do you have any suggestions as to how to move forward? I have the shapefile and now I need to...? Should I be converting it and if so are there any applications you suggest besides the ones I am using because they aren't working. I have QGIS to convert to DXF but then can I convert it to FBX in Maya? Last time I tried to upload either the shapefile or the DXF to Maya, it says unrecognizable file. Sorry for all the questions I am just so confused! Thanks

Comment: @JessicaNapolitano Do you know how to use Maya? Can you program in C#? If the answer to both of these is yes then I can help. Otherwise, you should watch some tutorials on these two then come back. You need those for this but I want to make sure it is something you can do before posting anything.

Comment: I do know how to program in C#. I just downloaded Maya but I have been poking around in it a lot. Let me know what you think and I can figure it out. I just need a bit of direction.

Comment: Ok. I will put an answer that will point you to the right place. Make sure to be using @username in the future to reply to people so that they will be notified. I wasn't notified.

Comment: @Programmer Ok great! Thank you. I look forward to your answer

Comment: @Programmer I was just wondering if you posted the answer somewhere else. Thank you

Comment: OMG. Totally forgot about this. I will open Maya today and show you how to do this with 3 states. You can then do the rest with the steps I will post. I apologize for this and will do by the end of today or Sunday but it wont be later than that.

Comment: @Programmer Hi I just wanted to check in and see if you had posted the answer in another place? Sorry I am new to posting to forums. Take your time. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Do you have Maya 2016 and Unity 5.5 installed on your computer? Tell me when you have them installed.

Comment: Hi Yes I do! @Programmer

Comment: Ok. There you go! Check the answer. It may look complicated but it's not. If you do **2.Creating each state Model** 3 or 4 times, you will get used to it. You have to do the **2.Creating each state Model.** for every State before you can continue with **3.Export as FBX**. There is an animated image for each step and I suggest that you look at each one to make sure you are doing it right. If you have a question, you can leave it here or under the answer.

Comment: You are amazing!!!! Thank you so much @Programmer I will take a look and try it out but I really appreciate it. I don't have a high enough level on Stack over flow to like your answer below but I do!

Comment: I know you don't. That's fine. Just one thing, if you finish it, upload a picture that shows you were able to do it. In that case I will know that this answer is not  useless. You are welcome !

Answer (score 11):

[image]

The answer below describes how do accomplish that. This was done with just **8** States for demonstration purposes.

There are **4** steps to do this but each step may have another step inside it. Create the model, export it and import it into Unity, add `Mesh Collider` to each one, detect click with `OnPointerDown` then change the color of the clicked GameObject,.

You need *Maya 2016* and *Unity 5.5* for this.

First thing to note is that Maya has a simple menu and option menu.

If I say "(option menu)", I am talking about the box that is next to the menu on the right side. Take a look at the image below for the difference between menu and option menu:

[image]

Make sure to check if any of instruction below has "(option menu)" in it.

**1.Creating Image Reference for modeling the states**.

**A**.Get reference map image.

Find a black and white image reference of the U.S. states. I will be using [this](http://alabamamaps.ua.edu/contemporarymaps/usa/basemaps/usstates1.jpg) one so download it.

**B**.Make Image Plane with the reference file.

Open Maya and create new Project and Import the the state image you downloaded.

To do this, go to *Create* --> *Free Image Plane*.

Under *Image Plane Attribute*, Select the icon in the *Image Name* then put the path of the image map reference you downloaded there.

[image]

**C**.Switch to Front view.

Select the *Image Plane*, position your mouse in the middle of the view then press the SPACE key on the keyboard. You will see four camera views. Move your mouse to the *left-bottom* view (*Front View*) then press the *SPACE* key again. Maya will switch to Front View. You will be working in Front View.

Now, Press `F` to zoom into the Image Plane.

[image]

**D**.Put the *Image Plane* in a layer then lock it.

Once the camera is zoomed in *Image Plane*, select the *Image Plane* again if not selected then click on *Channel Box/Layer Editor*.

Now, click on *Layers* --> *Create Layer from Selected*. There are three *checkboxes* on the created layer.

Continue to click on the third(last) *checkboxes* until it says "R". The "R" will lock the *Image Plane* so that it can't be selected again or interfere when modeling.

[image]

**2.Creating each state Model**.

**A**.Create curve
Go to *Create* --> *Curve Tools* --> *Pencil Curve Tool*

Draw any state one by one by holding down the left mouse button and tracing it around the chosen state. Leave a little space between the beginning and end of the line.

I will draw Nebraska as an Example.

[image]
**B**.Close the curve.

Select the curve then go to *Curves* --> *Open/Close*

[image]

**C**.Create a Nurbs Plane to cover the whole shape of curve you drew.

Select the curve then go to *Modify* --> *Center Pivot*

You will use this curve to cut out its shape from the Nurbs Plane.

Go to *Create* --> *NURBS Primitives* then make sure that *Interactive Creation* and *Exit On Completion* are both checked/enabled.

Go to *Create* --> *NURBS Primitives* --> *Plane*.

Hold down the Left mouse button then drag and move the mouse to create a Plane. Make sure that the size of the Plane covers the shape of the state drawn in step *2A*.

[image]

**D**.Project the curve to the surface

Select **both** the **Plane** created in step **2C** and the **curve** created in step **2A**.

You do that by holding down the left mouse button and drag the mouse cursor over both of them then release.

Both Objects should now be selected.

Go to *Surfaces* --> *Project Curve on Surface*

[image]

**E**.Trim the selected object.

Select the Plane from Step *D*.

Go to *Surfaces* --> *Trim Tool*

Click inside(middle) of the curve then press *Enter*.

The shape of the curve should now be cut out of the Plane,

[image]

**F**.Delete History then Center the pivot.

Select everything created in this process(Left click and hold then move mouse around everything then release).

Go to *Edit* --> *Delete by Type* --> *History*.

Go to *Modify* --> *Center Pivot*

[image]

**G**.Convert the NubSurface Plane to Polygon because Unity and other Game Engines uses Polygon.

Select the Plane from Step *E*.

Go to *Modify* --> *Convert* -->*NURBS To Polygons (option menu)*

Use the Settings Below:

*Type: Quads*

*Tessellation method: Standard fit*

*Chord height ratio: 0.54*

*Fractional tolerance: 0.01*

*Minimal Edge length: 0.001*

*3D delta: 0.0461*

Click Apply.

Now, you have a polygon, rename it to the appropriate state name(Nebraska).

[image]

**H**.Delete Objects behind

With the polygon still selected.

Go to *Modify* --> *Freeze Transformations*

Go to *Modify* --> *Center Pivot*

Move the polygon away. After this, delete every other objects(NubSurface and curve) behind it.

Select the polygon again then go to *Modify* --> *Reset Transformations*. This will bring the polygon back to its original position.

Go to *Modify* --> *Center Pivot*

[image]

**I**.Add Material the state created.

Go to the *Rendering* tab.

Click on the Round Icon which is a *Blinn* material. It will create a Blinn Material. Name it "State_Material". If you have already created "State_Material", you don't have to create a new one.

Go to Rendering Mode.

Select the polygon.

Go to *Lighting/Shading* --> *Assign Existing Material*--> *State_Material*.

The goal is to assign one material(State_Material) to all State/polygon. This will prevent having to export 50 materials to Unity.

[image]

**J**.Automatically Map the UV.

Go to *UV* --> *Automatic*

[image]

**K**.Delete History then Center the pivot of the converted Object.

Go to *Edit* --> *Delete by Type* --> *History*.

Go to *Modify* --> *Center Pivot*

[image]

**Done! Jump back to 2.Creating each state Model. and do the-same for the rest of the state.**

**3.Export as FBX**.

**A**.Export as Fbx.

Select all the States. I have 8 in my scene.

Go to *File* --> *Export Selection...(option menu)*.

Change *File type* to *FBX export*.

Click the *Export Selection* Button

Choose the Directory and file name then click *Export Selection* again.

[image]

**4.Using Maps in Unity**.

**A**.Import the Fbx into Unity.

Open Unity, go to *Assets* --> *Import New Asset...*

Choose the directory and FBX file saved through Maya.

[image]

**B**.Attach Mesh collider to each State/Plane.

Drag the Map to the Hierarchy.

Select all the states/models then go to *Components* --> *Physics* --> *Mesh Collider*.

[image]

**C**.Position the model to camera view.

Had to rotate the Object to 180 deg in y-axis then scale the x and y axis to 100. If you followed this tutorial exactly like like this with the-same image reference, then you will have to rotate and scale it the-same way.

[image]

**D**.Setup Event System

Go to *GameObject* --> *Create Empty* then name it "EventSystem".

Go to *Component* --> *Event* --> *Event System*.

Go to *Component* --> *Event* --> *Standalone Input Module*.

Select the "Main Camera" and go to *Component* --> *Event* --> *Physics Raycaster*. I said *Physics Raycaster* not *Physics 2D Raycaster*

[image]

**E**.Attach test Scripts

Go to *GameObject* --> *Create Empty* then name it "MapManager".

Select the *MapManager* GameObject and attach the `MapManager` script to it.

Select all the states/Model except for the parent Object then attach `MapClickDetector` script to all of them. Doing it once is easier.

[image]

**Description of the Script**:

The `MapClickDetector` script will detect mouse click, mouse over and other mouse actions then send it to the *MapManager* script. You can then do whatever you want in the `MapManager` script. It also sends the Map GameObject that is clicked so that you can get the name of the State.

To detect a click,  `IPointerDownHandler` is implemented then `OnPointerDown` is used to detect which state in the map is clicked. You can also use [Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) but `IPointerDownHandler` is is better since it prevents problems with the UI.

**MapManager** script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MapManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    Color normalColor = Color.red;

    Color mouseDownColor = Color.green;
    Color mouseEnterColor = Color.yellow;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void mapclick(GameObject objClicked)
    {
        Debug.Log("Clicked: " + objClicked.name);
    }

    public void mapMouseDown(GameObject objClicked)
    {
        Debug.Log("Pointer Down: " + objClicked.name);

        MeshRenderer mr = objClicked.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        mr.material.color = mouseDownColor;
    }

    public void mapMouseUp(GameObject objClicked)
    {
        Debug.Log("Pointer Up: " + objClicked.name);

        MeshRenderer mr = objClicked.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        mr.material.color = normalColor; ;
    }

    public void mapMouseEnter(GameObject objClicked)
    {
        Debug.Log("Pointer Enter: " + objClicked.name);

        MeshRenderer mr = objClicked.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        mr.material.color = mouseEnterColor;
    }

    public void mapMouseExit(GameObject objClicked)
    {
        Debug.Log("Pointer Exit: " + objClicked.name);

        MeshRenderer mr = objClicked.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        mr.material.color = normalColor;
    }
}
```

**MapClickDetector** script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class MapClickDetector : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler, IPointerDownHandler,
    IPointerUpHandler, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    MapManager mapManager;

    void Start()
    {
        addPhysicsRaycaster();

        mapManager = GameObject.Find("MapManager").GetComponent<MapManager>();
    }

    void addPhysicsRaycaster()
    {
        PhysicsRaycaster physicsRaycaster = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<PhysicsRaycaster>();
        if (physicsRaycaster == null)
        {
            Camera.main.gameObject.AddComponent<PhysicsRaycaster>();
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        mapManager.mapclick(gameObject);
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        mapManager.mapMouseDown(gameObject);
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        mapManager.mapMouseUp(gameObject);
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        mapManager.mapMouseEnter(gameObject);
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        mapManager.mapMouseExit(gameObject);
    }
}
```